# Learning ASP MVC by example. Bonus: an example that uses MVVM in microsoft's MVC framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvvm

I feel it is time to graduate from webforms to mvc. I've been programming webforms, and jquery for a long time.

Can you all suggest your favorite resources to learn this technology?

Bonus: I'm particularly interested in using a ViewModel (not necessarilly a MVVM framework) to pass my information around. Are there any good resources out there?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Google (for learning) and Knockout.js (for view models)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind books I recommend Steven Sanderson's MVC book(s), the latest being "Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework". It contains a very lengthy introducion and many good tips. After the intro it continues being very thorough and complete about MVC's features and extension points.

http://www.apress.com/9781430234043

You may want to wait for the MVC 4 edition though (each MVC version had a book so far).

Careful with ViewModels. In MVVM context it is a model with 'controller' methods. You'd do this client side.

A ViewModel in a MVC context can also be a domain model projection tailored to a view. Instead of passing a full domain model object to a view one would map a subset of it or perhaps expand some bits of it's detail data to a ViewModel that is an exact fit for what the view would present. Similarly you could have an EditModel that contains additional data for instance to supply the view with a list of selectable/possible values.

Answer (score 1):

There are countless good ASP.NET MVC tutorials on the web. The best place to start is with the samples provided by Microsoft on the MVC site: http://www.asp.net/mvc/samples

For MVVM, you can look at a JavaScript library called [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) which handles the view models on the client side.

As you progress, you can start exploring single page apps (SPAs) with MVC which combines some of the more advanced features of ASP.NET MVC with frameworks such as Knockout to produce a fully functioning app all on one page. A good example of that is the [BigShelf Sample SPA from Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/spa-samples/sample-bigshelf-application).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't get any clearer than this example by Microsoft:

- [Intro to ASP.NET MVC 3 (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3) to start with ASP.NET MVC and
- [Views and ViewModels](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3) to start with View Models

By the same token there are numerous samples, examples and tutorial on the web, but the one I've mentioned is your next step to begin with, gives you an essence what what is this ASP.NET MVC about...

Hope this is of help to you & good luck with ASP MVC